# Magento 2 : Product Price on website does not change

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Preconditions

```
Magento version 2.2.4
```

Steps to reproduce

```
Add 1 configurable product
While adding the product add 2 new configurable attributes (Model , Thickness both of type Textual Swatch)
Add 3 simple products for this configurable product
Each product has 3 Swatches color, Thickness and model.
Price of product different for three different model whereas color and thickness is same across all three prodcuts
```

Expected result

```
On product detail page it should change the prices of the product when clicking on model only
```

Actual result

```
On product detail page it changes prices of product when Model + Color + Thickness is clicked, else it keeps showing 1 price for all
```

Comment: There is an own stackexchange for magento: https://magento.stackexchange.com/